# Java профайлер

Tags: eclipse, профилирование, java, intellij-idea

Подскажите толковый профайлер для Java. Желательно с интеграцией в Эклипс, на крайний случай в Идею.

Comment: а VisioVM ктото юзал?)

Answer (score 4):

YourKit, правда без интеграции

Comment: Судя по описанию, у YourKit есть интеграция во все популярные ИДЕ: Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans, JBuilder 2008 R2, JDeveloper. см. http://www.yourkit.com/features/index.jsp#ide_integration
Пользуюсь Идеей - с интеграцией проблем не было!

Answer (score 1):

JProfiler (вроде отдельное приложение, без интеграции, но зато очень удобное)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько он толковый, но в Eclipse входит встроенный профайлер TPTP.

[Статья о нём](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t52038.html). [Ещё одна](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
В перспективe Memory Analysis можно взять дамп памяти любого запущенного java-приложения (утилита командной строки есть в JDK) а потом проанализировать утечки. Удобно.